# VBA Shell function fails to execute Python scripts when the name of the directory has space

Tags: python, vba, excel, shell

My VBA program is as below,

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ret_val As Variant
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.path
    ret_val = Shell("C:\Python27\python.exe " & ThisWorkbook.path & "\Hello.py", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

My python script `Hello.py` in the same directory of the workbook containing the VBA code is as below,

```
for i in range(1000):
    print "Hello"
```

---

Enter `?"C:\Python27\python.exe " & ThisWorkbook.path & "\Hello.py"` in Excel immediate window gives me `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Company\Folder 1\Hello.py`. In this case, if I run `Test()` from Excel VBA, I get a flash of the dark prompt window, as if it is opened but without running the python script.

But if I renamed the folder name `Folder 1` to `Folder1` (notice now there is no space in the name of the directory), running `Test()` from Excel VBA will show up the prompt window and I can see "Hello" written to the screen for a while.

---

It looks to me that I can't contain space in any folder name when using Shell function in VBA. But what really causes this bug and how do I fix it so that I can use a folder whose name has space?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the file name in quotes - I'm not a VBA user, but would `"C:\Python27\python.exe """ & ThisWorkbook.path & "\Hello.py"""` work? This hopefully gives you `C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Company\Folder 1\Hello.py"`.

Comment: `CHR(34)` produces a double-quote in VBA

Answer (score 0):

This may work, it uses the Chr(34) to produce a double-quote before the path name and after the filename.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ret_val As Variant
    ChDir ThisWorkbook.path
    Dim command As String
    command = CHR(34) & "C:\Python27\python.exe" & CHR(34) & " " & CHR(34) & ThisWorkbook.path & "\Hello.py" & CHR(34)
    ret_val = Shell(command, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like we don't need to do the same trick to the application, i.e., `"C:\Python27\python.exe "`, even if the directory name `Python27` changes to `Py thon27` someday?

Comment: Yes, you can install python wherever you like, so if you moved it you would need to. I've updated the answer to reflect that.